# find all li's which has ul/uls's under a class in angularjs without jquery

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-jqlite

Basically , I want to get all li's which has ul under it and then append an icon to it. e.g:

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li>child1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>grandchild1</li>
    </ul>
    <li>child2</li>
</ul>
```

In the above scenario i want to change the color of `li-child1` and not of `li-child2`

I don't want to use jquery. 
Can I achieve it with only angularjs?

Comment: You should create one directive for these type of scenario.

Comment: can you please share one example? @MayankVadiya

Comment: Actually you can go through @Groben answer. It is good way.

Comment: Thanks @MayankVadiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a value from your scope it should be quite easy. If in your controller you have this:

```
ctrl.parent = {
    name: 'toto',
    childs: [{
      name: 'tata',
      childs: [{
        name: 'titi'
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'tutu'
    }]
  }
```

Then you could loop over it in html with `ng-repeat`:

```
<li class="child" ng-repeat="child in $ctrl.parent.childs">
  <span ng-bind="child.name"></span>
<li>
```

You could also add a class depending on the fact that this child has childs aswell:

```
ng-class="{'withChilds': child.childs && child.childs.length >0}"
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vrkpq7e/1/)

The best way, would be to create a component that takes a child in entry and loops over it

See the same thing with a component: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vrkpq7e/2/)

Comment: thanks @groben for the quick response. But i am getting the data populated using a custom directive
<ul class="treeview">
                 <li ng-repeat="branch in treeData">
                     <a href="#">{{branch.label}}</a>
                     <collection  collection='branch.children'></collection>
                 </li>
             </ul>
So can any way i can do this after the page load. Something like in jquery
$('.treeview').find('li').has("ul").each(function(){ then do the stuff})

Comment: It's not a problem, you just have to bind the correct values to your component. My answer is just to give you the general idea. I added a version that uses a component.

Comment: Got it @groben. Thanks a lot .